# Using keyword in FileInfo

Tags: c#

I am writing following code.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             FileInfo fiobj = new FileInfo(@"e:\mohan.txt");
             Console.Write("Name of file:"+ fiobj.Name);

             using(StreamWriter sw = fiobj.AppendText())
             {
                sw.WriteLine("mohan!");
             }
        }

    // code not working

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           FileInfo fiobj = new FileInfo(@"e:\mohan.txt");
           Console.Write("Name of file:"+ fiobj.Name);

           StreamWriter sw = fiobj.AppendText();            
           sw.WriteLine("mohan!");            
        }
```

When I use the "using(){}" block I am able to write into file but when I wrote the same code without using(){} block I am not able to do So.
Why is So? 
As far as I know using(){} block specifies the scope of the object for it's life time.
Does using(){} block doing something fancy here to make it enable to write the data to file.

Comment: Please define "I am not able to do So"? what happens? Note that `using` calls `Dispose()`, which would close the file - but since you don't do anything *after* it, there shouldn't be a noticeable difference here (the `using` version is more correct, note)

Comment: What error do you get without the `using` block? Is it possible that the file is still locked from an earlier run of the application (e.g. it works the first time)?

Comment: @Marc if he runs the program many times one of the processes might be locking it

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am just not able to write into it.

Comment: @Mohan then you probably just need to flush

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `using` is shorthand for correctly ensuring that your object is `Disposed` correctly once the scope falls outside of the `using` block.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
StreamWriter sw = fiobj.AppendText();
try
{
    sw.WriteLine("mohan!");
}
finally
{
    if (sw != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)sw).Dispose();
    }
}
```

This code correctly closed and disposes of the StreamWriter. Without it, it would remain locked.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Without the `using` statement, you aren't closing the `StreamWriter`.
Therefore, the StreamWriter remains open and the file remains locked.

Comment: Just for curiosity having question in mind that "As .NET provide managed code isn't it the responsibility of CLR to close the StreamWriter?"

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, but the GC is non-deterministic.  Any `IDisposable` objects should always be explicitly disposed in `using` blocks as soon as possible.